# How to disable auto change the position of curly brackets in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio

I want the brackets this way:

```
void fun() {
    cout<<"I am OM"<<endl;
}
```

VS Code ruins it in this way:

```
void fun()
{
    cout<<"I am OM"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Change the title of this question to "how do I change the bracing style in VScode" and you'll get better answers. You want the k&r style instead of the Allman style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the styling with the VS code extension: [Visual Studio Code Format](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryannaddy.vscode-format)